# Voxel remesher making mesh look like it has flat shading

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I am currently sculpting a model and trying to combine the neck and head together. So, I Booleaned them together:

[image: Booleaned sculpt]

And then I *tried* to use the voxel remesher with a voxel size of 0.0025 m and smoothed normals, but was greeted with this unfortunate disappointment:

[image: Remesh sculpt]

As you can see here, the voxel remesher produces a shape that looks flat-shaded, even though I have Smooth Normals on. Here are my Voxel Remesh settings:

[image: Voxel Remesh settings]

I am using Version 2.91.0, and since both the neck and head were created with Subsurf, they only contain quads (although there is some weird geometry at the Boolean intersection). What is the reason for this happening? How can it be solved?

I'll provide more information if necessary.

Comment: it looks like it's the way the voxel remesh, it doesn't seem to respect the topology, maybe try Instant Meshes? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l88hQj16IhA

Comment: @moonboots I'll check it out, but I'll stick around to see if there's a solution with the Blender remesher. Thank you!